# Endomorphism ring of infinite dimensions vector space

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noncommutative-algebra

Let $D$ be a field, $V$ an infinite dimension vector space over $D$, put $R=\operatorname{End}(V)$. It is clear that $R$ is a non-commutative Ring. What is the form of simple submodules of  $R$? Is there any book study the properties of the ring $R$?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There is an [expository paper by Orsatti and Rodinò](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-011-0443-2_32) about classifying left and right ideals in $R$.

Answer (score 4):

Because the ring is prime, all of its minimal right ideals (simple submodules of $R_R$) have to be mutually isomorphic. (If there were two that weren't isomorphic, the two semisimple components generated by these two isoclasses would have product zero, contradicting the ring's primeness.)

One particular simple minimal ideal is the one generated by a map whose image has dimension $1$ (and the rest are isomorphic.)

Another interesting thing to know is that the right (and left) socle of $R$ is the collection of endomorphisms with finite dimensional images.

The ring you are describing is currently [89% complete in the Database of Ring Theory](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/rings/ring/15/) which should keep you busy with lots of its properties.

Some of the most important properties are that it is right and left primitive, von Neumann regular and right self-injective, but not Dedekind finite and not unit regular.

Comment: Thank you for answering. How can we prove that the right socle of $R$ is the collection of endomorphisms with finite dimensional image? Is there a book show that?

Comment: @Mu.faith it probably appears in exercises in books.  I bet it probably appears in Lam’s lectures on rings and modules, but I would just advise proving it yourself. It’s not hard.

Comment: may you give me a hint to proving this case?

Comment: @Mu.faith do you agree the transformations with 1-dimensional images are in the socle?

Comment: Thank you very much.  Now I see the big picture.

Comment: @rschwieb For the DaRT: The endomorphism ring of an infinite dimensional vector space over a field $F$ is not PI. Suppose it is; then it satisfies a polynomial identity of minimum degree $d$, hence so does its subalgebra $M_d(F)$, a contradiction since $M_d(F)$ cannot satisfy any PI of degree less than $2d$.

Comment: @rschwieb For the DaRT: Not Armendariz either. According to the DaRT, matrix rings are not Armendariz and this property passes to subrings.

Comment: @JoseBrox Hi!  Thanks for the messages!  I see you dropped them in the webform on the site which is a good idea. If you use Git that's also a good way, but the webform is fine.

Comment: @JoseBrox [This ring](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/rings/ring/44/) should also be non-PI, non-Armendariz for the same reasons, I think. You concur?

Comment: @rschwieb That algebra $A$ is not PI: Suppose $f$ is a minimal degree multilinear PI for $A$ (it exists over any field), of degree $d$. Then $f(x_1,\ldots,x_d)=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n} a_\sigma x_{\sigma(1)}\cdots x_{\sigma(d)}$ with $a_{\text{id}}=1$. We have the elements $e_{ij}\in A$, for any $1\leq i<j\in\mathbb{N}$, which satisfy $e_{ij}e_{kl}=\delta_{jk}e_{il}$. Therefore $f(e_{12},\ldots,e_{dd+1}) = e_{12}\cdots e_{dd+1} = e_{1d+1}\neq 0$, contradiction.

Comment: @rschwieb That algebra A is not Armendariz either: Consider the polynomials $f(x)=e_{12}x+e_{13}$, $g(x)=e_{34}x-e_{24}$ of $A[x]$. Then $fg=0$ but $e_{13}e_{34}\neq 0$.

Comment: @JoseBrox [Another ring](http://localhost:8000/rings/ring/142/).  Isn't it true that $B\otimes_kB$ would have $B$ as a subring (on the diagonal) and then also contain copies of $M_n(K)$ in $S$ as (nonunital subrings) and so would not be Armendariz?  And also, would not be PI for the aforementioned reasons.

Comment: @JoseBrox Sorry i gave a local link in the last one: it should be [this](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/rings/ring/142/).  [This other ring](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/rings/ring/93/) also qualifies for the same reasons, I think. As well as [this too](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/rings/ring/80/)

Comment: @rschwieb Yes, I agree on everything! Alternatively, for $B\otimes_k B$ we can also resort to Regev's theorem, which states that the tensor product of two PI algebras is PI. We can constructively show that it is not Armendariz: put $E_{ij}:=e_{ij}\otimes e_{ij}$. Then the polynomials $f(x):=E_{11}x+E_{12}$, $g(x):=E_{22}x-E_{12}$ satisfy $fg=0$ with $E_{12}E_{22}\neq0$.

Comment: @JoseBrox I'm not sure how Regev's theorem can be useful to show $B\otimes_kB$ is _not_ PI but I'm glad to learn about it.

Comment: @rschwieb Sorry, that was just faulty logic on my part, a result of me answering in a rush (someday I should really learn not to do that :) ); clearly, Regev's theorem works for the opposite question. Since $B$ is unital and $k$ is a field, the easiest way to see $B$ as a subalgebra of $B\otimes_k B$ would be as $B\otimes_k 1$.